trying to remove this faint watermark - but end up getting a blue tint in matplotlib display
I am working on a project that requires removing a specific type of watermark from the background of certain pictures (typically STEM-related, as this is for an educational project). To begin, I attempted to remove the watermark from the following picture:
this is the picture i tried to remove it from

you'll probably have to zoom in to see it; but it says examgoal
however, for some reason, the output i got, though it was far from ideal, was tinted in blue. i have no idea why this happened and have been working on this for hours; but couldnt find a solution

i ran the following code on google colab; which did kinda (very poorly, though) get rid of the watermark. for your reference, i used matplotlib, numpy as well as cv2.
i would really appreciate some help on how to go about this, because i'm also trying to generalize this process for multiple pictures.
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()
for filename in uploaded.keys():
    print(f'Uploaded file name: {filename}')
image_path = filename
image = cv2.imread(image_path)


if image is None:
    print(f"Error: Unable to load image at {image_path}")
else:
    print("Image loaded successfully")


gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
enhanced = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
adaptive_thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(enhanced, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                                        cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(adaptive_thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)
mask = cv2.bitwise_not(morph)
result = cv2.inpaint(image, mask, 3, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.title('Original Image')
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.title('Image without Watermark')
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()


everyone's always on scientists and also engineers about ethics. I think here you're removing someone's watermark without permission. as such, I find it prudent to refuse to help. watermarks are designed to be hard to remove. it's kinda like CAPTCHAs. we won't help break those either.

is your question about matplotlib's coloring of your data? or about removing watermarks? -- is all that code absolutely required to repro the problem? [mre]. read it thoroughly and make sure to understand it please.

@ChristophRackwitz thank you for you reply! i understand your hesitancy. my main question is about matplotlib colouring my data blue. i'm sorry for not reading that before posting; this is my first post here. it won't happen again

@Adi this is because opencv likes BGR and matplotlib likes RGB, use cv2.cvtColor to convert or read the image with plt.imread. This can be considered a duplicate question, as a lot of previous questions addressed this problem

This question is similar to: OpenCV imshow doesn't need convert from BGR to RGB. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also, in case your png has an alpha channel, remember to use cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED

@TinoD's suggestion about the alpha channel does the trick in this case. You have to load the image with cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED. Then, you can split the alpha and RGB channels, process the RGB as you have already done, and finally re-add the alpha channel before plotting.

@TinoD actually no, it's NOT because of channel order. the source picture is entirely blue, and the text is modulated using the alpha layer.

@Luca that didnt do much unfortunately :(

Set the color map (cmap) to gray in the plt.imshow. See https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormaps.html

@ChristophRackwitz Fair fair, I didn't take a deep look at the image, gave it my two best guesses

As correctly suggested by @TinoD, the problem is caused by the fact that you are treating the image as RGB/BGR, but it also has an alpha channel that get lost with your implementation.
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()
for filename in uploaded.keys():
    print(f'Uploaded file name: {filename}')
image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
image_original = image.copy()

if image is None:
    print(f"Error: Unable to load image at {image_path}")
else:
    print("Image loaded successfully")

# Split RGB and alpha channel
rgb   = image[:, :, :-1]
alpha = image[:, :, -1]

# Process the RGB channels
gray = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
enhanced = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
adaptive_thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(enhanced, 255, 
                                        cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                                        cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(adaptive_thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)
mask = cv2.bitwise_not(morph)
result = cv2.inpaint(rgb, mask, 3, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)

# Re-apply the original alpha channel
result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)
result[:, :, -1] = alpha

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.title('Original Image')
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image_original, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGBA))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.title('Image without Watermark')
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGBA))
plt.show()

You will get your images with the expected background color.

As you can see, this solves you problem with matplotlib's coloring of your data.
For the watermark removal part, as @Christoph Rackwitz mentioned, you will have an hard time getting help to infringe someone else's copyright on SO.

Here is your picture's channels shown individually (BGRA):

As you can see, the colors contain almost no information. The text is encoded in the alpha channel. That is as it should be, for the alpha channel to work properly.
When OpenCV loads an image, it discards the alpha channel by default. You're getting just the first three channels. That looks like so:

So no, matplotlib is not to blame. Matplotlib does not apply any coloring here. Nor is there a mismatch of channel orders. You correctly handled that (cvtColor with BGR2RGB).
This is purely a consequence of OpenCV discarding the alpha channel by default. You have to load the image with cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED to get it.
Even then, OpenCV's cv.imshow doesn't know how to handle it. Matplotlib does.
